# pgfgantt, creating titles with various sizes

Tags: pgfgantt

I was wondering if there was any easy way to create multiple title sizes in pgfgantt? For example, I have a year title, and then underneath that titles representing each quarter of the year and I would like the year title to be larger than the quarter title. However, if I simply change the text size of the year title (using the \gantttitle[title label font={\Huge}]{}{} then the text disappears underneath the title beneath it.

I can increase the y unit title but this then applies to all of the title lines. Is it possible to do this for an individual line?

My example is shown below.

Thanks!

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{center}
 \begin{ganttchart}[
  x unit=2.0cm, y unit title=0.4cm, y unit chart=0.6cm, vgrid,
  title/.append style={draw=none, fill=RoyalBlue!50!black}, title left shift=0.01, title right shift=-0.01,
  title label font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
  title label node/.append style={below=-1.6ex},title height=1,
  bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=OliveGreen!75},
  bar height=.3, bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!90}, bar label text={#1\hspace*{0.1cm}},
  group right shift=0.05, group top shift=.6, group height=.1, group peaks height=.2, group peaks width=0.1, group left shift=-0.05,
  group label node/.append style={align=right}, group label text={#1\hspace{0.2cm}},
  milestone left shift=0.94, milestone right shift=0.06, milestone height=0.4, milestone label text={#1\hspace*{0.1cm}},
  bar incomplete/.append style={fill=Maroon}]{1}{8}
  % Titles
  \gantttitle[title label font={\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}}]{2013}{3}\gantttitle[title label font={\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}}]{2014}{5} \\
  \gantttitle{Q4}{3}\gantttitle{Q1}{3}\gantttitle{Q2}{2}\\
  \gantttitle{10}{1}\gantttitle{11}{1}\gantttitle{12}{1}\gantttitle{1}{1}\gantttitle{2}{1}\gantttitle{3}{1}\gantttitle{4}{1}\gantttitle{5}{1} \\
  \ganttset{progress label text={}, link/.style={black, -to}}
  % Part 1
  \ganttgroup{Part 1}{1}{4} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=25, name=T1A]{Task 1}{1}{3} \\
 \end{ganttchart}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
```